# Preventing Unity on Android Detecting User Input on Splash Screen?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When my Unity app starts up in Android on an older device I get a momentary black screen, then the splash screen and then another momentary black screen.

The problem is that the app is receiving user input during the second momentary black screen (before the user can actual see anything).  I think Unity thinks that the initial Scene is displayed (but it hasn't been).

Is there a good way to prevent this initial input from registering?

Comment: You can try having it load to a loading page first and then to the actual scene but I'm not sure if it will stop the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding one more splash screen which can act as Loading screen and load the next level from it using

LoadLevelAsync

this way u will not have the issue of that black screen taking the input.